pip install dedupe not working for python 3.11
While doing pip install dedupe getting following error .
Python installed is 3.11 . Please help I am trying collect cluster id using dedupe . Running it from pycharm .

  Building wheels for collected packages: affinegap, doublemetaphone
      Building wheel for affinegap (pyproject.toml) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × Building wheel for affinegap (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [10 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          running build_py
          creating build
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\affinegap
          copying affinegap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\affinegap
          running build_ext
          building 'affinegap.affinegap' extension
          error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for affinegap
      Building wheel for doublemetaphone (pyproject.toml) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × Building wheel for doublemetaphone (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [10 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          running build_py
          creating build
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\doublemetaphone
          copying doublemetaphone\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\doublemetaphone
          running build_ext
          building 'doublemetaphone.doublemetaphone' extension
          error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for doublemetaphone
    Failed to build affinegap doublemetaphone
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for affinegap, doublemetaphone, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
    
    [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 24.0
    [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip



Have you tried installing the VS Build Tools for C++?

@Plagon thank you so much for sharing correct link. This helped and it got installed

It could be an inherent problem with pip, you can try to reinstall pip like this: python -m ensurepip --upgrade while in your virtual environment.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
